# What is the difference between ${\bf P ^{\bf FewP}}$ and ${\bf UP ^{\bf FewP}}$?

Tags: complexity-classes

What is the difference between ${\bf P ^{\bf FewP}}$ and ${\bf UP ^{\bf FewP}}$ ? In other words, what is the language that can be decided by ${\bf UP ^{\bf FewP}}$, but cannot be decided by ${\bf P ^{\bf FewP}}$ assuming that ${\bf P} \not = {\bf UP} \not = {\bf FewP}$.